# Compute the discrete log

Tags: cryptography, discrete-logarithms

How can I compute the discrete log of $7$ and $11$ modulo $2311$ with respect to
the primitive root $(3, 11)$, using the Pohlig-Hellman method.
However, Pohlig-Hellman method is for small prime, so how can I deal with the large number?
I need to find $11=7^x \mod 2311$. How can I compute the discrete log with respect to the primitive root $(3, 11)$?

Comment: It would be best to ask this on the cryptography stack I believe.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You've cited the algorithm. What is your problem following it? Show your work, please, and where you're stuck. Then you're more likely to get an answer rather than downvotes.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  It's an algorithm, so you just do it, though it takes the right inputs.

Comment: How is $(3,11)$ (a pair) a primitive root? Do you mean just $3$?

Comment: Start by factoring $2310$, I'd say.

Comment: Pohlig-Hellman is for groups with smooth orders, not for small primes.